# There should be no [untagged] questions

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tag-cleanup-request

The tag [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is applied to questions which either have all their tags burninated or to questions migrated from other sites whose tags from the origin site do not match any tags here. According to formal advice given by the SE team, this tag can be created at any time and should be edited out on any question that contains it ASAP so that they are properly categorized (otherwise they could just languish as noise).

This question is to serve as a formal tag cleanup request for the [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag and should indefinitely be marked [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) even if the tag is clear, because it can be recreated at any time. Why am I asking this request? Because then it will show in the [list of tags that need cleaning](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/tag-cleanup-request+status-planned), because many users use this to bring up a full list of tags that need cleaning. I should also mention that in the old monthly tag cleanups, we also had an explicit warning against this tag.

Comment: I expect `untagged` to be the last resort tag available on any site if I can't think up any related tags and the system won't allow me to post the question with zero tags. This allows editors to help me to tag the question correctly. Better to explicitly mark the question `untagged` than to mark it with random tag just to got though the barrier.

Comment: @Vi. Please see [SO's tag wiki for untagged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: What shall the user use if all existing tags seem "not exactly that"? [tag:i-dont-know-which-tag-to-put-here]? On meta there's "discussion" tag that usually can act as universal one... But it won't work on the main site.

Comment: @Vi. This is the exact reason why this request exists. If there is any [tag:untagged] question, it will be replaced by another user (who knows that the tag isn't supposed to exist). However, your info really only applies if the user has the necessary rep needed to create new tags (most of the time); otherwise, they would need to use some other tag.

Comment: @Vi. The [tag:untagged] tag is now blacklisted across the network, which means it's impossible for regular users to use it: it can *only* be applied per the special circumstances above (which do happen, by the way)